# How to make xmpp request on port 443 or 80?

Tags: xmpp, strophe, tigase

I have developed a chat app using xmpp protocol. Using tigase. I have enabled ssl using port 5281. Everything works fine. But I have to connect to app.abc.com:5281. Always I have to mention port in Url which is not allowed in some firewalls. I tried proxypass which works perfectly but increase load time.

What is another solution for same? Is any? I heard about web sockets but can not change my application architecture now. Please suggest.

Comment: which library are you using to connect to xmpp ??

Comment: Strophe js. Javascript library.